# dijit/form/FilteringSelect: How can I trigger an onchange event manually

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to set a value to the dijit FilteringSelect and then call an event manually.

I tried it like this:

```
registry.byId( "mySelect" ).value = "11";
registry.byId( "mySelect" ).change();
// Tried with onchange() also
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to change the value of your widget.

```
registry.byId( "mySelect" ).set('value', 11);
```

This will fire automatically `onchange` on your widget.

Please note you should always change a value of your widget property using a `setter`, this will maintain a "proper" life-cycle execution.

For a more advanced scenario:

In case you add custom property of using a custom widget you should define custom setter.

More information can be found here:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase.html